# Where can find Service Ceiling of an aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-performance, aircraft-limitations, cessna-172

I would like to figure out the service ceiling for Cessna 172N and I couldn't find it anywhere in the POH.

Where can I find it? In POH or somewhere else? If in POH, please post a snapshot of it.

Comment: You should use the answer to this question as reference only. The specific ceiling of your aircraft may differ due to configuration or other limitations/alterations and you should use the POH/Reference Cards/Airworthy Certificate for your specific 172 for the most accurate answer.

Comment: How do you find the service ceiling? Start climbing and then just keep climbing until it stops climbing....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in the [Pilots Operating Handbook](http://www.skywarriorinc.com/downloads/POH%20BOOKS/172N%20POH.pdf) allright.

[image: Pilots Operating Handbook]

As @Dave pointed out, this value can change depending on configuration and other limitation/alterations.

Answer (score 5):

It is in the pilot handbook, [before the title page [PDF]](http://www.skywarriorinc.com/downloads/POH%20BOOKS/172N%20POH.pdf), under "performance-specifications"

[image]